# Is the declaration "const typedef enum" valid in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, constants, typedef

I thought enums were static, what's the point of a `const enum`?

For example:

```
const typedef enum
{
    NORMAL_FUN = 1,
    GREAT_FUN = 2,
    TERRIBLE_FUN = 3,
} Annoying;
```

I have had an old program dropped on my head that I am being forced to work with (from an equipment manufacturer), and I keep coming across enums being defined with `const typedef enum`.

Now, I am used to C#, so I don't fully understand all the C++ trickery that goes on, but this case appears to be straightforward.

From the coding of the program it would appear that variables that are of type `Annoying` are meant to be changed, everywhere, all the time.

They aren't meant to be constant. Long story short, the compiler doesn't like it.

This sample was written back sometime prior to 2010, so this could be some kind of version difference, but what did/does `const typedef enum` even mean?

Comment: Whoever wrote that really likes noise. Not to mention nonsense.

Comment: What is messing with my head is that I have compiled binaries that work as per expectations, and the source code to them which I'm being forced to work with (kicking and screaming), and yet somehow I have Annoying variables that are apparently modifiable. I am used to C++ programs being full of arcane trickery, and this is either some bit of arcane that was recently patched or the result of someone sabotaging the source code after the binaries were built.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That makes the type-alias `Annoying` constant, so all variables declared with that type-aliases are constant:

```
Annoying a = NORMAL_FUN;
a = GREAT_FUN;  // Failure, trying to change a constant variable
```

Comment: Good enough for me. I am guessing there was never any alternate meaning and the working binaries were created before someone spiked the code by throwing "const" in everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`const typedef Type def;` and `typedef const Type def;` mean the same thing, and have for many years. There's nothing special about the case where `Type` is an `enum` definition, and you can see it too in:

```
const typedef int const_int;
const_int i = 3;
i = 4; // error
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing

```
typedef enum
{
    NORMAL_FUN = 1,
    GREAT_FUN = 2,
    TERRIBLE_FUN = 3,
} Annoying;
```

has the advantage of the `enum` working nicely in C too, which handles `typedef` by introducing `Annoying` into the *typedef namespace*. So the provider of the `enum` declaration *could* be also targetting C.

Using the `const` qualifier means that you cannot write code like

```
Annoying foo = NORMAL_FUN;
foo = GREAT_FUN; // this will fail as `foo` is a `const` type.
```